# SQLite INSERT Fails with Exception but Record Shows Up in Database

Tags: python, sqlite, locking

I try to track down a bug in my `python` program where two processes are accessing a `sqlite` database.

- **Process 1** is reading periodically
- **Process 2** is inserting periodically

If for whatever reason the insert fails I designed my `python` application to append the failed insert to a buffer and retry it on the next insert attempt via `executemany`.

I recently found out that the database has **duplicate entries**.
I can reproduce the behavior with the following code. The code is running on very slow hardware that's why I faked long taking queries and decreased the lock timeout.

`process1.py`:

```
import sqlite3
import time

con = sqlite3.connect("data.db", timeout=0.1)
con.executescript("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data (counter int NOT NULL);")
con.create_function("sleep", 1, time.sleep)

while True:
    try:
        with con:
            con.execute("SELECT counter, sleep(1) FROM data LIMIT 1;")
    except sqlite3.OperationalError as e:
        print("Reading failed. Ex: {}".format(e))
    time.sleep(0.25)
```

`process2.py`

```
import sqlite3
import time

con = sqlite3.connect("data.db", timeout=0.1)
counter = 0

while True:
    try:
        with con:
            con.executemany("INSERT INTO data (counter) VALUES (?);", [(counter,)])
    except sqlite3.OperationalError as e:
        # con.rollback()  # possible workaround?
        print("Writing failed at '{}'. Ex: {}".format(counter, e))            
    counter += 1
    time.sleep(0.25)
```

When you run the code in two separate terminals to mimic the problem described above you can see that **Process 2** throws an `OperationalError` with the message *database is locked*. So far so good.

The weird thing is that when you query the database the seemingly failed inserts are there anyway. Is this by design?

---

The behavior is different when you switch **Process 1** from reading to writing. Now the failed inserts from **Process 2** won't show up in the table.

`process1_extended.py`:

```
import sqlite3
import time

con = sqlite3.connect("data.db", timeout=0.1)
con.create_function("sleep", 1, lambda x: time.sleep(1) or x)
con.executescript("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data (counter int NOT NULL);")
counter = 1000000  # distinguishes between the two writing processes

while True:
    try:
        with con:
            con.executemany("INSERT INTO data (counter) SELECT sleep(?)", [(counter,)])
    except sqlite3.OperationalError as e:
        print("Writing2 failed. Ex: {}".format(e))
    counter += 1
    time.sleep(0.25)
```

I am aware that an [`INSERT`/`DML` statement](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-controlling-transactions) operation is different from a `SELECT` and that is has something to do with different kind of locks (shared lock vs exclusive lock) but what I can't explain to myself are the two different results. How can I prevent `sqlite` from inserting data when an exception is thrown?

*`con.rollback()` in the except block of **Process 2** seems to be a workaround but I am unsure if that implies other caveats. And shouldn't this be applied automatically by the [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager)?*

---

**Addition to the answer:**

The exception within **Process 2** if **Process 1** is reading occurs at the commit within the context managers [`__exit__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_sqlite/connection.c#L1741) because of the shared lock. If *the other* lock is pending a rollback is tried because an exception occured earlier and the `__exit__` method is invoked with the arguments [`exc_type/exc_value/exc_tb`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_sqlite/connection.c#L1735) set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably the difference between locks (SHARED v. RESERVED). From [SQLite Doc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html)):

> An attempt to execute COMMIT might also result in an SQLITE_BUSY return code if an another thread or process has a shared lock on the database that prevented the database from being updated. When COMMIT fails in this way, the transaction remains active and the COMMIT can be retried later after the reader has had a chance to clear.

In the read example, it is a SHARED lock, the transaction remains active and gets COMMITed after the next successful INSERT. I know the [API doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager) says the context manager will rollback. But I also know what I see.

The connection object has an `in_transaction` attribute:

> `True` if a transaction is active (there are uncommitted changes), `False`
>   otherwise. Read-only attribute.

I added some `print`s to my repro and found that, in fact, the transactions were staying active *when the insert failed.*

```
before insert  0  in tx?  False
after insert  0  in tx?  False
before insert  1  in tx?  False
Writing failed at '1'. Ex: database is locked  in tx?  True
before insert  2  in tx?  True
Writing failed at '2'. Ex: database is locked  in tx?  True
before insert  3  in tx?  True
Writing failed at '3'. Ex: database is locked  in tx?  True
before insert  4  in tx?  True
after insert  4  in tx?  False
before insert  5  in tx?  False
Writing failed at '5'. Ex: database is locked  in tx?  True
before insert  6  in tx?  True
Writing failed at '6'. Ex: database is locked  in tx?  True
before insert  7  in tx?  True
Writing failed at '7'. Ex: database is locked  in tx?  True
before insert  8  in tx?  True
after insert  8  in tx?  False
before insert  9  in tx?  False
Writing failed at '9'. Ex: database is locked  in tx?  True
before insert  10  in tx?  True
Writing failed at '10'. Ex: database is locked  in tx?  True
before insert  11  in tx?  True
```

All rows were inserted. The explicit rollback would prevent this problem.